# Как переместить json файл и js файл который использует информацию из него в сборочную папку webpack и при этом сохранить рабочим путь

Tags: javascript, json, webpack

Собираю проект на webpack. Структура такая:

app - выход webpack

src(вход) > js > primer.js | prediction.json

в primer.js есть следующий код:

```
const data = require(./prediction.json);
const people = Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => ({
  name: key,
  percent: Math.round(value * 100)
}));

export default people;
```

Нужно чтоб при сборке проекта в папке app > js > (тут) генерировались primer.js (это я сделал) и prediction.json с учетом того, что данные в этом json файле именно уже в собранном проекте (паке app) в дальнейшем будут изменятся и primer.js должен динамично их использовать.

Но я столкнулся с проблемой, когда я пытаюсь перенести json файл в папку сборки используя и

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin({
     patterns: [
       { from: 'js/prediction.json', to: 'js' },
       { from: 'js/prediction.json', to: 'js', noErrorOnMissing: true }, 
     ],
   }),
```

и

```
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        use: ['file-loader'],
        type: 'javascript/auto',
      },
```

даже такие вариации

```
      // {
      //   test: /\.json$/,
      //   use: {
      //     loader: 'file-loader',
      //     options: {
      //       outputPath: 'js', 
      //       name: 'prediction.json', 
      //     },
      //   },
      //   type: 'javascript/auto', 
      // },
```

а так же меняю различные способы подключения json к primer.js, даже пробовал создать отдельную переменную под путь, но всегда получаю один из этих вариантов:

1. если использовать только CopyWebpackPlugin то во время сборки проекта js файл который формируется меняется так, что он перестает считывать то, что находится в json в данный момент, вместо этого он просто передает ту строку, которая находится в json в момент сборки
2. ошибка типа:
   Module build failed (from ../node_modules/json-loader/index.js):
   SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0
   at JSON.parse ()
3. Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Подскажите как решить данный вопрос, может кто-то сталкивался с подобным. Заранее спасибо.

содержимое конфига вебпак:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CssMinimizerWebpackPlugin = require ('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin');
const TerserWebpackPlugin = require ('terser-webpack-plugin');
const ImageMinimizerPlugin = require("image-minimizer-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');


const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
const isProd = !isDev;

const filename = (ext) => isDev ? `[name].${ext}` : `[name].[contenthash].${ext}`

const optimization = () => {
  const confObj = {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all'  
    }
  };

  if (isProd) {
    confObj.minimizer = [
      new CssMinimizerWebpackPlugin(),
      new TerserWebpackPlugin(),
      new ImageMinimizerPlugin({
        minimizer: {
          implementation: ImageMinimizerPlugin.imageminMinify,
          options: {
            plugins: [
              ["gifsicle", { interlaced: true }],
              ["jpegtran", { progressive: true }],
              ["optipng", { optimizationLevel: 5 }],
              [
                "svgo",
                {
                  plugins: [
                    {
                      name: "preset-default",
                      params: {
                        overrides: {
                          removeViewBox: false,
                          addAttributesToSVGElement: {
                            params: {
                              attributes: [
                                { xmlns: "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" },
                              ],
                            },
                          },
                        },
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                },
              ],
            ],
          },
        },
      }),
    ];
  }

  return(confObj);
};

module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    index: './js/main.js',
    upload: './js/upload.js',
    result: './js/result.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app'),
    filename: `./js/${filename('js')}`
  },

  devServer: {
    
    static: {
      directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app'),
    },

    historyApiFallback: true, 
    open: 'firefox', 
    compress: true, 
    port: 3000,
  },

  optimization: optimization(),

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.html'),
      filename: 'index.html',
      chunks: ['index'],
      minify: {
        collapseWhitespace: isProd
      }
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/upload.html'),
      filename: 'upload.html',
      chunks: ['upload'],
      minify: {
        collapseWhitespace: isProd
      }
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/result.html'),
      filename: 'result.html',
      chunks: ['result'],
      minify: {
        collapseWhitespace: isProd
      }
    }),

    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),

    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: `./css/${filename('css')}`
    }),

    // new CopyWebpackPlugin({
    //   patterns: [
    //     { from: 'js/prediction.json', to: 'js' },
    //   ],
    // })

    // new CopyWebpackPlugin({
    //   patterns: [
    //     { from: 'js/prediction.json', to: 'js' },
    //     { from: 'js/prediction.json', to: 'js', noErrorOnMissing: true }, 
    //   ],
    // }),

  ],

  devtool: isProd ? false : 'source-map',

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        loader: 'html-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(?:gif|png|jpg|jpeg|svg)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: `./img/${filename('[ext]')}`
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [{loader: 'babel-loader'}]
      },
      // {
      //   test: /\.json$/,
      //   use: {
      //     loader: 'file-loader',
      //     options: {
      //       outputPath: 'js', // Путь в папке сборки
      //       name: 'prediction.json', // Имя сохраняемого файла
      //     },
      //   },
      //   type: 'javascript/auto', 
      // },
      // {
      //   test: /jsonPath\.js$/,
      //   use: ['json-loader'],
      // },
      // {
      //   test: /\.json$/,
      //   use: ['file-loader'], // Используйте file-loader для копирования JSON-файлов
      //   type: 'javascript/auto',
      // },
      // },
      // {
      //   test: /\.json$/,
      //   use: 'json-loader'
      // }

    ]
  }

}
```

Comment: Покажите содержимое файла webpack.config.js.
Используете ли плагин "json-loader"?

Comment: содержимое добавил (все что в комментариях - это попытки переноса json). json-loader использовать пытался.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в файле "webpack.config.js" закомментирована часть кода.

Напишите так:

```
plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: 'src/js/prediction.json', to: 'js' }
      ]
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        use: 'json-loader',
        type: 'javascript/auto'
      }
    ]
  }
```

А файле primer.js:

```
import data from './prediction.json';

const people = Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => ({
  name: key,
  percent: Math.round(value * 100)
}));

export default people;
```

Теперь при сборке проекта, плагин **copy-webpack-plugin** скопирует файл **prediction.json** из папки **src/js** в папку **app/js**, сохраняя путь. Затем, с помощью загрузчика **json-loader**, JSON файл будет корректно загружен в коде **primer.js**.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение!

Comment: Если ответ оказался полезен, прошу отметить его как ответ =)